# How to use email address in an if statement from a list in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to populate the two grids based on the ending part of the email address.

My `if` condition is not working and all the records are landing in the `tblExternal`.

`varAttendeeId` is a variable and the result is the list of campaign members.

There is a mapquery function that returns the list of record(s) selected.

Please suggest how I can use the email address from the mapquery in the if statements here.

```
function addAttendeetoCampaign(){
        varAttendeeId = '';
  jq( ".attendeeChk:checked" ).each( function() { varAttendeeId+=jq(this).val()+","; } );

        if(varAttendeeId != '') {
            var result= Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.EventPortal_Detail.addToCampaignMember}',
                                                                                                                            varAttendeeId,
                                                                                                                            CToken,
                                                                                                                            UToken,
                                                                                                                            EToken,
                                                                                                                            function handleResultresponse(result, event) {
                    if (event.status){
                            // Insert a row in the External Invitees table as the last row if type is External
                            for( i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                                if (varAttendeeId.indexOf('xyz.com') != -1) {
                                    var tableRef = document.getElementById('tblInternal').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                                    result.forEach(function(record) {
                                        // Insert a row as the last row
                                        var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

                                        // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
                                        var newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
                                        var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
                                        var newCell3  = newRow.insertCell(2);
                                        var newCell4  = newRow.insertCell(3);
                                        var newCell5  = newRow.insertCell(4);
                                        var newCell6  = newRow.insertCell(5);

                                        // Append a text node to the cell
                                        newCell1.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].strName;
                                        newCell2.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].CompanyName;
                                        newCell3.innerHTML = "";
                                        newCell4.innerHTML = "";
                                        newCell5.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].strEmail;
                                        newCell6.innerHTML = "";
                                    })
                                }
                                else
                                { //Else Insert row as the last row in External Invitees table
                                    var tableRef = document.getElementById('tblExternal').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                                    result.forEach(function(record) {
                                        // Insert a row in the table at the last row
                                        var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

                                        // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
                                        var newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
                                        var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
                                        var newCell3  = newRow.insertCell(2);
                                        var newCell4  = newRow.insertCell(3);
                                        var newCell5  = newRow.insertCell(4);
                                        var newCell6  = newRow.insertCell(5);

                                        // Append a text node to the cell
                                        newCell1.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].strName;
                                        newCell2.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].CompanyName;
                                        newCell3.innerHTML = "";
                                        newCell4.innerHTML = "";
                                        newCell5.innerHTML = mapAttendeeQuery[record.AttendeeId].strEmail;
                                        newCell6.innerHTML = "";
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
            {escape: true});
        }   
}
```

Comment: can you just print console.log(varAttendeeId) and tell us what exactly you are seeing there ?

Comment: Aside: you really need to learn how to 1- indent your code, 2- use functions (the only difference in your if / else is the name of the element you update). 3- assign functions to variables so you don' t have such a christmas tree.  Doing the above will make your code so much more readable.

Comment: And two more feedback, 1. Use Regex instead of indexOf as its more specific     var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@xyz.com$/;
    re.test(email);    2. Your code has lots of duplicate lines, except the var tableRef all the code in else block is same as in if block

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine that this fixes your problem, but re-formatted and with a new function added I think it's clearer to see what it's actually doing.  I'm not convinced it makes any sense...

```
function createNewAttendeeRows( result, tableName, attendees ) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById( tableName ).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    result.forEach( function( record ) {
        // Insert a row as the last row
        var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

        // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
        var newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
        var newCell3  = newRow.insertCell(2);
        var newCell4  = newRow.insertCell(3);
        var newCell5  = newRow.insertCell(4);
        var newCell6  = newRow.insertCell(5);

        // Append a text node to the cell
        newCell1.innerHTML = attendees[record.AttendeeId].strName;
        newCell2.innerHTML = attendees[record.AttendeeId].CompanyName;
        newCell3.innerHTML = "";
        newCell4.innerHTML = "";
        newCell5.innerHTML = attendees[record.AttendeeId].strEmail;
        newCell6.innerHTML = "";        
    }
}

function addAttendeetoCampaign(){

    varAttendeeId = '';
    jq( ".attendeeChk:checked" ).each( function() { varAttendeeId+=jq(this).val()+","; } );

    if(varAttendeeId != '') {
        var result= Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                        ( '{!$RemoteAction.EventPortal_Detail.addToCampaignMember}',
                                            varAttendeeId,
                                            CToken,
                                            UToken,
                                            EToken,
                                            function handleResultresponse(result, event) {

                                                if (event.status){
                                                    for( i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                                                        var tableToUpdate = 'tblExternal';
                                                            if (varAttendeeId.indexOf('xyz.com') != -1) {
                                                                tableToUpdate = 'tblInternal';
                                                            }
                                                            createNewAttendeeRows( result, tableToUpdate, mapAttendeeQuery )
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            {escape: true}
                                        );
    }   
}
```